# Encourage (XeLa)TeX to break pages at the end of sentences within a paragraph

Tags: xetex, page-breaking, arabic

As the title suggests, I am using XeLaTeX to layout very long paragraphs (up to 50 pages in length for a single paragraph), and would like to encourage it to break pages at the end of sentences within a paragraph as opposed to the middle of sentences. Currently, it seems equally happy to break at either. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to consider switching to LuaTeX?

One added complication, I am typesetting in Arabic, and the punctuation used to demarcate one sentence from the next is non-standard (these are Ayat in a Quranic Mashaf).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I know nothing about this stuff, but it sounds like it requires altering the line breaking, right?  Otherwise every sentence might end in the middle of a line.

Comment: For the second requirement [Amiri](http://www.amirifont.org) font provide `\char"06DD` as Ayats separator just type `\char"06DD١` to obtain `١` inside it.

Comment: @salimbou , yes, I am using the Ayat separator, I just wanted to point out to whoever was answering the question that it differs from the English full-stop, and so their answer should not depend on that fact.

Comment: @Mark, I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. The point is that I would like the page break to coincide with the end of a sentence. The sentences are small enough that this can be accomplished fairly easily. With proper adjustment of inter-word spacing, the last sentence on the page can be made to fully-fill the last line as well. This is something Arabic calligraphers and scribes have done for centuries when hand-writing the Quran, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do this with XeLaTeX, or whether I need to switch to LuaTeX.